# Setting Tumble window according to a calendar week (from Mon to Sun)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I'm currently using Flink for a stats project.
In my final elastic search index, I'm supposed to divide data entries by calendar weeks.

Example:

```
ES index data {
-period: 03/06/23 - 03/12/23
-aggregated data: mydata for this period
}
```

I was thinking of using Group Window Aggregation with a TUMBLE but :

1. I can't use WEEK as a Time Period
2. (the real problem) even if I use - TUMBLE(7, DAY) the "week" will be based on the 7-day period following the first flink inbound stream.

My question is basically this: is it possible to set a Window TUMBLE by calendar week (Monday to Sunday) in Flink ?

Apologies for the lousy English,

Thanks,
Thomas

I was trying to get a Window Aggregation through TUMBLE on a Calendar Week basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll need to use a KeyedProcessFunction to do a very specific per-week aggregation. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990582/flink-windowing-aggregate-and-output-to-sink) for more details.